# How to add allowDiskUse to mongooperation.find method in spring boot

Tags: mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

The below query i want to add `allowDiskUse true`. I am able to add allowDiskUsage to aggregation query but not able to find a solution for find method

```
Query query = new Query().with(pageable).addCriteria(criteria).collation(collation);
mongoOperations.find(query, RuntimeApplication.class, RUNTIME_APP);
```

I want to know is that possible to add allowDiskUsage to find method or i need to change query to aggregation.

i just found in below query from internet. but i am not getting how to convert it into spring boot

```
db.collection.find(<match>).sort(<sort>).allowDiskUse()
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of spring-data version are you using? You should be able to add `allowDiskUse` to the `Query` object just like this:

```
val query = Query()
    .with(Pageable.ofSize(1))
    .addCriteria(Criteria())
    .allowDiskUse(true)
```

And then afterwards use the query with find for instance with `mongoTemplate`.

Here is the documentation: https://javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework.data/spring-data-mongodb/latest/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Query.html